# im trying to make it so when a user inputs a certain word or words it opens up google but cant figure it out

Tags: python-3.x

This is how far i got, thanks in advance.

```
open_webpage = ("google", "open web", "open google", "internet", "go to","find",)
def openweb(user_response):
for word in user_response.split():
    if word.lower() in open_wepage:
        return webbrowser.open("www.google.com")
```

Comment: Note the typo in `if word.lower() in open_wepage:`

Comment: thanks fixed but still not working :(

Comment: If you have edited your code and its still nt working then please edit your question with your updated code

Comment: please also share sample user inputs. In your current form your code will never work with things like "open web" or "go to" for example as these will first be split you will then search for each individual wordin your list of words. there is no item in your list called "open" or "web" or "go" or "to". So these will never work. So the question is why do you split the input? if i user your code with the type fixed this works for me if i dont split the input and type something like "go to"

Answer (score 0):

In your code other than the typo issue in the code the issue you have is you split the user input. So if user input was `open web`. your code will split that. It will then check your list for an item which is equal to `open` it wont find this. So it will then search your list for an item equal to `web`. It also wont find this. So it wont open the browser. If you stop splitting the input and just check the user input in the list then it will work.

```py
import webbrowser

def openweb(user_response):
    if user_response in open_webpage:
        print("launching the browser")
        return webbrowser.open("www.google.com")
    print("input not in list")

open_webpage = ("google", "open web", "open google", "internet", "go to", "find",)
user_input = input("What do you want to do?: ")
openweb(user_input)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
What do you want to do?: open web
launching the browser
```